Jenkins Job Fails to Execute Script: "create.computer.sh not found"
I’m running a Jenkins job that is supposed to execute a script from my Helloworld repository, which in turn calls a shell script located in my Jenkins repository. However, I'm encountering an error stating that the script create.computer.sh cannot be found.
Jenkins Job Configuration: The job is configured to run a script using the following command:
#!/bin/bash
./create.computer.sh

Error Message: The Jenkins console output shows: create.computer.sh not found.
Question:
How can I modify my Jenkins job to correctly locate and execute the create.computer.sh script?
Additional Information:
I have verified that create.computer.sh exists in the Jenkins repository.
The script is executable.
Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Jenkins Job Configuration: The job is configured Please show the jenkins job configuration. How is the job configured?
